# Passing buffer from SuperpoweredAndroidIO to Java InputStream / Android NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, superpowered

I am using the amazing Superpowered library (SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO) for low-latency recording of audio. While the basic concepts are clear to me, I want to **pass the recorded audio (which arrives in a buffer) back to an InputStream in Java** (without recording to a file), from which I can then read the recorded audio and process it.

I guess this question could also be more generally asked - how to feed an InputStream in Java from a periodically updated buffer in C++?

Comment: Yes, I understand - thanks a lot for the surprisingly simple suggestion, I'll give it a try and let you know how well it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the suggestion I received in a comment turned out to be a simple and working solution:
**Creation of pipe in C++:**

```
 if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "C++", "Error creating pipe");
 }
...
```

Passing file descriptor to Java:

```
...
    return pipefd[0];
...
```

**Then in Java/Android:**

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream underlyingStream;
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.adoptFd(getFD());
underlyingStream = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(pfd);
```

Worked well for me, but of course I'm still happy to receive other suggestions.